# Email Link Unable to open on outlook

Tags: hyperlink, outlook, html-email

In my project i integrated html email for reset password option.User click on link and if user  submit his email he will get mail having link to reset his password.
The link is opening on Gmail. But the same link is not working when I open in Out look. It is non clickable mode.
Is html email won't workout on Outlook? or coding any change required to integrate.
Please reply?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the issue. In my web page having some commented code. When I removed the commented code now the mail is coming properly and all the links are working. I believe this commented code has some influence in terms of security concern of outlook.
So when ever write the mail function etc need to make the page is very clean and all unwanted comments etc should be removed.